# PHP, FileSetup from LocalHost to Public Server

Tags: php, server, configuration, localhost

So I was wondering about requirements regarding File-Setup to an online Server, as I'm actually using a Localhost.

1. **Document Root:** I use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] / http / folder / file.php` to navigate to all my files:

> if I change to a Server, I do not have to make any changes regarding the path?

2. **file privancy:** Mostly, I use classes & methods in those files.

> If I upload all Files to the Server, does a user have access to them (eg. typing url/folder/file) &  isit possible to process/access them somehow as external user?
> How to provent this the most easy way? (I heard about .htaccess, or using Server-rootfolder), but there is a simple php code to check if its a linked file?

3. There are any other very important remarks regarding **FILE setup** from localhost to public Server? So, user are not able access sensitive data from Files (eg. DB Connection, datahandling, etc.)

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: If a user opens a .php file, the server should send only the php output, not the source code, that’s the difference between client-side and server-side languages, if you want to make some folders inaccessible, you could use `deny from all` in .htaccess in that folder.

Comment: You should also add `Options -Indexes` in your .htaccess, so users can’t see contents of directories without index.php or index.html.

Comment: Thank you: for eg. they could be able to see the object? public $Output = NULL; $this->output = Carlson; - protected $Output, they are not able to see?